# php going up a directory -- cannot get to work

Tags: php

I am trying to include a .php file, but to do so I need to go up two directories, however I cannot seem to make it work. Here is my code:

```
<?php include '../asset/scripts/php/portfoliohome.php'; ?>
```

Here is what the file structure looks like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\website\pages\index.php
```

I am wanting to go from `index.php` up to `website`, and then I can include the `.php` from `/asset/scripts/php/portfoliohome.php`.

portfoliohome.php location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\website\asset\scripts\php\portfoliohome.php
```

This is the error I receive:

> Warning: include(.../asset/scripts/php/portfoliohome.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\website\pages\index.php
>   on line 1

Comment: so what's the full filesystem path for portfoliohome.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go up 2 directories use `../` twice

```
<?php include '../../asset/scripts/php/portfoliohome.php'; ?>
```